# ng-grid how to style columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am a bit of an angularjs noob so here goes. 
Trying out the ng-grid (http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) and I am interested in the Excellike editing example (ref to plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OxJqS5LYOvG2vx0Ujhu7?p=preview)

I could not figure out from reading the angulargrid documentation page how to style individual columns. What I would like to do is disable/enable a single column based on the value of another column in this grid. For example (does have any practical value but anyway) if in the plunker example the namecolumns starts with M the age column in that row should be disabled.

grid plunker example looks something like this:

```
Name | Age
Mark | 25 -> the age column should be disabled
Ed   | 31 -> the age column should be enabled
```

How can I set the style for an individual column based on the value of another one? Also how can I make the age field editable/noneditable (enabled/disabled) depending on the name column in that row?

Answer (score 0):

from ColumnDefs Options

```
cellClass   ''  Appends a css class for the column cells    Link
```

for each column you can provide the cellClass.

along with that you can use the ng-class, if you want further control based on values in the row...

Comment: if I set the cellClass property it styles the whole column for all rows, I just need it for 1 row. Also how do I get a reference to another columnvalue in a certain row?

Comment: for 1 row or multiple rows: you need to define the function which returns boolean for rows to be styled: and use rowTemplate like in this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/fGhK5VNwFH6GNakZ1TVq?p=info

Comment: still does not show cellclass conditionally depending on other column in that row

Comment: Can you put up a plunker

Comment: can we add multiple cellClass, like cellClass: 'My_RightAlign, My_BGRed, My_FWBold' ??